# Running code before app starts, the best way in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am building the application, for server monitoring and monitoring data filtering. This app uses the legacy code of Zabbix monitoring tool frontend which has some config files that needs to be included and some classes to work with database.

There are 3 main things that I should do before start interacting with the database:

```
DBstart();

$serviceFactory = new CApiServiceFactory();

API::setApiServiceFactory($serviceFactory);

CWebUser::login($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], '');
```

How can I or should I integrate these steps while using Silex?

API class with static method calls are used all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any valid php code before Silex application starts:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

// the code you like to execute before the app starts goes here
DBstart();
$serviceFactory = new CApiServiceFactory();
API::setApiServiceFactory($serviceFactory);
CWebUser::login($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], '');

// Silex app starts:
$app->run();
```

But you should really think in terms of services and refactor your legacy code to make use of pimple container to actually **integrate** it. E.g.:

```
$app['serviceFactory'] = $app->share(function () {
    return new CApiServiceFactory;
});
....
// later, when you need the API:
API::setApiServiceFactory($app['serviceFactory']);
```

Comment: Yeah, you can add all those calls inside the before ([APP wide middleware](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#before-middleware))